# Accessing Kotlin class object from Java

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a Kotlin class which has a class object, e.g.

```
public class Foo {
    public class object {
        public val SomeValue : Int = 0
    }
}
```

If I'm using this class from Java, how do I access SomeValue inside the class object? If it were a Java class with a static property, I'd just use Foo.SomeValue - but I can't do that here.

IntellIJ shows that I can access `Foo.object.$instance`, but `$instance` doesn't have getSomeValue or anything like that. If I try to use $instance.SomeValue anyway, when I build the error message says:

> SomeValue has private access in Foo.object

I'm using Kotlin 0.5.1.

Comment: You could also make it `@JvmStatic` allowing it to be accessed as a static member of the class `Foo`.  See full docs on interoperability from Java to Kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods-and-fields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "absense" of getSomeValue() is a bug in the IDE. If you use it, it compiles OK.
I created an issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-3337

Answer (score 32):

As a workaround, you should be able to make the Kotlin field visible using `@JvmField`:

```
@JvmField var addressLocationBox: ToOne? = null
```

Answer (score 7):

```
data class YourClass(@JvmField val name: String)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: As an explanation of why this works, if you are using a data class in Kotlin you need to add `@JvmField` in front of the variable definitions in the data class constructor if you want the variables to be accessible from Java.

Comment: My problem was the class defined in Kotlin was not recognized in the java code.  When I added @JvmField to one of the params, it suddenly knew about the class defined in the .kt file

Answer (score -1):

To set a custom name for the generated Java class, use the @JvmName annotation:

**Kotlin**

```
@file:JvmName("DemoUtils")

package com.example

class Util

fun getTime() { /*...*/ }
```

**Java**

```
new com.example.Util();
com.example.DemoUtils.getTime();
```

Moreover, if you use the **@JvmMultifileClass**, then:

```
@file:JvmName("Utils")
@file:JvmMultifileClass

package com.example

fun getDate() { /*...*/ }
```

**Java**

```
com.example.Utils.getDate();
```

Comment: You've just copied the Kotlin docs @ https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html