# How to call Kotlin class from Java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

I need to pass intent from java activity to Kotlin activity:

Java activity ProfileActivity.class:

```
 Intent selectGameIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt.getKotlinClass(CreateNewPollUserActivity.class).getClass());
                startActivity(selectGameIntent);
```

And this is my Kotlin activity:

```
class CreateNewPollUserActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_new_poll_user)


        val max = 45
        val min = 10
        val total = max - min}}
```

When i run it i have an error:

```
cannot find symbol
import com.myvote.Profile.ToolbarOption.CreateNewPollUserActivity;
```

any ideas how send intent from java activity to Kotlin activity?

Comment: `Intent selectGameIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, CreateNewPollUserActivity.class);
startActivity(selectGameIntent);`

Comment: CreateNewPollUserActivity.kt - This is a kotlin class file, it could not be called like a regular java class

Comment: why would it not work?

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
import com.Profile.ToolbarOption.CreateNewPollUserActivity;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class CreateNewPollUserActivity

Comment: yes, it can be called like a regular java class, just fix your import, [Calling Kotlin from Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html)

Comment: @IR42, this is my import:
import com.Profile.ToolbarOption.CreateNewPollUserActivity;
it's a same package...

Comment: in the question you have `com.myvote.Profile.ToolbarOption.CreateNewPollUserActivity`, so i think there is a problem in import, try to delete it and re-import CreateNewPollUserActivity with alt+enter

Comment: as you can see, i took my code directly from your page:
kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt.getKotlinClass(MainView.class)
and it is not working.
I've tried with alt+enter and it makes the import as i wrote before...
Unfortunately, it does not recognize it

Comment: ... you don't need `kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt.getKotlinClass`, just use `CreateNewPollUserActivity.class` ...

Comment: as I mentioned before, it's not works

Comment: `Intent selectGameIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, CreateNewPollUserActivity.class);` is all you need. Delete that import, then click on this line and Alt+Enter to get the option to add the appropriate import. If that doesn't work, tell us what the error is.

Comment: @Tenfour04, did it again, and got the same error:
error: cannot find symbol import com.Profile.ToolbarOption.CreateNewPollUserActivity; ^ symbol: class CreateNewPollUserActivity

Comment: The fact that the error is that it "cannot find symbol" and not "unresolved reference" suggests to me that you have a syntax error, like maybe a missing semicolon somewhere.

Comment: Itls refers me to import line. But i added import with alt enter and there is only one suggestion. It's super weird...

Comment: Since the issue is clearly with imports, it'd be helpful if you specified which packages both classes are declared in.

Comment: Egor: same package: com.myvote.Profile.ToolbarOption

Comment: i don't think it is possible to call kotlin class in java , you may be able to do the opposite..

Answer (score 14):

add this in build.gradle project

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

And on top of build.gradle module file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to use  call Kotlin class from Java class

```
 Intent selectGameIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, 
 CreateNewPollUserActivity.class);
  startActivity(selectGameIntent);
```

In your code, Probably the problem lays not in the Java-Kotlin relation, but in something else. Please check your code/project.

Comment: Checked twice, but the issue is still there.
Your answer is wrong. Unacceptable.

Comment: Can you please add your log

Comment: There is no log data since the error is on BUILD level:

C:\Users\dbokov\app\src\main\java\com\Profile\ProfileActivity.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
import com.Profile.ToolbarOption.CreateNewPollUserActivity;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class CreateNewPollUserActivity
  location: package com.Profile.ToolbarOption

Comment: The package name are same? Both fragment and activity

Comment: No, any error...
I think, maybe there is some implementation for kotlin i need to add to my gradle?
But, if so, how i can write Activitties in kotlin at all...

Comment: It's two Activities, and it both in the same package

Comment: Same same:
error: cannot find symbol
                    CreateNewPollUserActivity.class);
                    ^
  symbol:   class CreateNewPollUserActivity

Answer (score 0):

For this aim, you need to do several steps:

1-**build.gradle project**

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10'
```

2- **build.gradle app**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

3- Introduction the class and fun:

**kotlin kt:**

```
class CountTime(val activity: Activity) {
fun seeNext(t: String, c: String, ico: Int, i: Int) {
```

**java MainActivity**

```
CountTime countTime = new CountTime(this);
countTime.seeNext(t,c,ico,i);
```

and if there is a **companion object**

```
.Companion.getInstance();
```